# Java final class with constant

Tags: java, class, oop, static, final

I must define a class which all it does is hold constants.

```
public static final String CODE1 = "100";
public static final String CODE2 = "200";
```

Now I want use these values in other classes. Is it better to use this class as a static class or instantiate it ?

Thanks.

Note : I know enums but in this context, I must use a class.

Comment: As your fields are static there is no reason to instantiate your class. Could you explain why enums are no solution as they are classes too.

Comment: if you use static values, instantiate the class wouldn't give you a advantage

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Just to use the values, you certainly shouldn't instantiate the class. Just because you *can* access static members as if they were instance members doesn't mean it's a good idea.

If the class really only contains constants - and if you're sure that's a good idea, rather than those constants appearing within classes which are directly related to them - you should make it a `final` class with a private constructor, so that no-one *can* pointlessly instantiate it:

```
public final class Codes {
    public static final String CODE1 = "100";
    public static final String CODE2 = "200";

    // Prevent instantiation
    private Codes() {
    }
}
```

Don's answer suggesting using an enum is a very good idea too - it means you can use `Code` in your API everywhere that you *don't* need the exact string representation, which prevents you from accidentally using non-code values.

Comment: Can't we instantiate it using reflection?

Comment: @Kartic: Only be calling `setAccessible` or whatever... and it wouldn't do any *harm*, it's just not *intended* to be constructed. If people want to abuse reflection and they're running in a security manager that lets them do so, there's not a lot to be done about that.

Comment: @Kartic `throw new UnsupportedOperationException()` in the constructor would prevent instantiation with reflection also.

Comment: @Dragan Bozanovic Yeah! I do agree.

Answer (score 4):

Jons answer is correct, although I want to show you a solution with an enum.
There is a disadvantage in accessing its String value as you have to call `Code.CODE1.text()` instead of `Code.CODE1`.

```
public enum Code {

    CODE1("100"), CODE2("200");

    private String text;

    Codes(String text) {
        this.text = text;
    }

    public String text() {
        return text;
    }
}
```

Comment: I'd call it `Code` rather than `Codes`, so that you can use it in an API taking a single `Code`... and probably rename the property to `getText()` or similar, but that's a minor matter :)

Comment: I wanted to stick with your answer, therefore I used `Codes` and didn't even considered thinking about naming. But you're right, I'll rename it. I also thought about overriding `toString()` to return `code`, but I don't wanted to lose the advantage of returning the enums name. Personally I dislike `getX()`methods for enums, so I'll go with `text()`.

Comment: Don, when you update your code, please also check if you used that code somewhere else in your answer and fix these places as well. Please check my edit to see where you've missed that.

Answer (score 0):

java language spec and JVM spec allow you to do anything you wanted, whether instantiate a class or use final or use other way....

Just use Eclipse and try !

while there is some good practice, Jon Skeet's answer is one good practice.

Answer (score 0):

Java Language is not support global variable

```
public class ComonFun {
    public static final String CODE1 = "100";
    public static final String CODE2 = "200";

    public static String CODE1(){
        return CODE1;
    }
    public static String CODE2(){
        return CODE2;
    }
}
```

implement

```
public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println(ComonFun.CODE1());
        System.out.println(ComonFun.CODE2());
    }
}
```

Comment: Java built in function Math...Example Math.PI

Comment: What's the reason to write getters for public static fields? You can access them without getters. Plus your naming violates the conventions as you are using uppercase letter for your methods.

Answer (score 0):

i think that you need simply to declare an interface, you won't need to specify the clause "public static final". and it can be usuable throgh the hall project.

Answer (score 0):

Use them as static, don't go for instantiation.

Even use static import as a benefit.

```
package coma;

import static coma.ImportStatments.*;

public class UsingClass {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println(CODE1);
    }
}
```

And the class with final variables would look like this:

```
package coma; 
public class ImportStatments {  
    public static final String CODE1 = "100";   
    public static final String CODE2 = "200"; 
}
```